# Use same tomcat instance on multiple URL

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a tomcat instance running on my server opxxx01 (FQDN : opxxx01.domain.com)
Everything working fine. But I want to display the same instance on another URL : quietude.anotherdomain.com

**I read a lot of topics about this** but nothing works for me :

On opxxx01.domain.com --> OK

On quietude.anotherdomain.com --> KO

Context :
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo); 
Tomcat 8.5.30; 
Apache 2.4.6

You can see my code below but nothing is displayed on quietude.anotherdomain.com.

Thanks for your help :)

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
        prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
        pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %S %D %F" />
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false" />
</Host>
<!-- I added these lines below -->
<Host name="quietude.anotherdomain.com"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
        prefix="quietude_access_log" suffix=".txt"
        pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %S %D %F" />
</Host>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it !

I the file **app.f2e312e439be13da8b85.js**, I change :

```
http://opxxx01.domain.com/downloads/quietude_result.csv
```

by

```
/downloads/quietude_result.csv
```

and in my file **Statistics.vue**, I change :

```
axios.get('http://opxxx01.domain.com/downloads/quietude_result.csv').then(response => {
```

by

```
axios.get('/downloads/quietude_result.csv').then(response => {
```